# Why is my function returning early unless I return `nullptr`?

Tags: visual-c++

I'm currently in the process of writing a function that tries to parse a .fbx file (the library used is a .c and .h pair that I compile together with my code, called ufbx) and I am puzzled by some behavior I'm seeing while debugging. The code looks like this, imagine there's a breakpoint on `ufbx_free_scene` at the end:

```
std::shared_ptr<geometry::Mesh> AssetManager::LoadFbxMesh(const std::string& fullFilePath)
{
    ufbx_load_opts opts = { 0 }; // Optional, pass NULL for defaults
    ufbx_error error; // Optional, pass NULL if you don't care about errors
    ufbx_scene* scene = ufbx_load_file(fullFilePath.c_str(), &opts, &error);

    if (!scene)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("Failed to load fbx file: " + fullFilePath + ": " + std::string(error.description.data));
    }

    bool meshFound = false;
    auto newMesh = std::make_shared<geometry::Mesh>();

    for (size_t ni = 0; ni < scene->nodes.count; ni++)
    {
        ufbx_node* node = scene->nodes.data[ni];

        if (node->is_root)
        {
            continue;
        }

        if (node->mesh)
        {
            if (meshFound)
            {
                throw std::runtime_error("Only fbx files with a single mesh are supported.");
            }

            meshFound = true;
            auto fbxMesh = node->mesh;

            for (size_t i = 0; i < fbxMesh->vertices.count; ++i)
            {
                auto pos = fbxMesh->vertices.data[i];

            }
        }
    }

    ufbx_free_scene(scene);

    return nullptr;
}
```

If I run the code as-is, the breakpoint is hit, it runs as expected. However, if I replace `nullptr` with the `newMesh` defined above, the breakpoint is never hit. Instead it jumps straight to the `return`, completely ignoring the for loop and the call to `ufbx_free_scene`.

I tried to look at the disassembly and it seems it introduces an early return right after it creates the new shared ptr? Why would it do that? The disassembly for the non-nullptr case looks like I'd expect (no early return).
[image: disassembly view]

I'm invoking `msvc` via `SCons`, if it helps this is the full command it ran (where only AssetManager was changed i.e. the class that contains my function):

```
scons: done reading SConscript files.
scons: Building targets ...
cl /FoduskEngine\asset\AssetManager.obj /c duskEngine\asset\AssetManager.cpp /TP /nologo /Od /std:c++20 /MD /EHsc /DEBUG /Zi /DTRACY_ENABLE /IduskEngine /IC:\Users\myuser\code\thirdparty\duskengine\glfw-3.3.7\include /IC:\Users\myuser\code\thirdparty\duskengine\glad\include /IC:\Users\myuser\code\thirdparty\duskengine\glm /IC:\Users\myuser\code\thirdparty\duskengine\boost_1_79_0 /IC:\Users\myuser\code\thirdparty\duskengine\tracy\public
AssetManager.cpp
link /nologo /DEBUG /OUT:a.exe /LIBPATH:. ./../thirdparty/duskengine/glfw-3.3.7/lib/glfw3.lib ./../thirdparty/duskengine/boost_1_79_0/stage/lib/libboost_container-vc143-mt-x64-1_79.lib ./../thirdparty/duskengine/boost_1_79_0/stage/lib/libboost_json-vc143-mt-x64-1_79.lib opengl32.lib kernel32.lib user32.lib gdi32.lib winspool.lib comdlg32.lib advapi32.lib shell32.lib ole32.lib oleaut32.lib uuid.lib odbc32.lib odbccp32.lib duskEngine\DuskMisc.obj duskEngine\main.obj duskEngine\asset\AssetManager.obj duskEngine\asset\Texture.obj duskEngine\asset\third_party\stb_image_impl.obj duskEngine\camera\Camera.obj duskEngine\editor\CameraController.obj duskEngine\editor\Editor.obj duskEngine\editor\EditorGUI.obj duskEngine\editor\InputManager.obj duskEngine\editor\gizmos\EditorGizmos.obj duskEngine\editor\gizmos\TransformHandles.obj duskEngine\editor\gui_subpanes\AssetBrowserGUI.obj duskEngine\editor\gui_subpanes\EntityListEditorGUI.obj duskEngine\editor\gui_subpanes\EntityPropertiesGUI.obj duskEngine\editor\gui_subpanes\ScenePropertiesGUI.obj duskEngine\imgui\imgui.obj duskEngine\imgui\ImGuizmo.obj duskEngine\imgui\imgui_demo.obj duskEngine\imgui\imgui_draw.obj duskEngine\imgui\imgui_impl_glfw.obj duskEngine\imgui\imgui_impl_opengl3.obj duskEngine\imgui\imgui_stdlib.obj duskEngine\imgui\imgui_tables.obj duskEngine\imgui\imgui_widgets.obj duskEngine\math\Math.obj duskEngine\projects\ProjectLoader.obj duskEngine\rendering\shaderset.obj duskEngine\rendering\opengl\GLModelRenderable.obj duskEngine\rendering\opengl\GLRenderer.obj duskEngine\scene\Scene.obj duskEngine\scene\SceneLoading.obj duskEngine\glad.obj duskEngine\asset\third_party\ufbx\ufbx.obj C:\Users\myuser\code\thirdparty\duskengine\tracy\public\TracyClient.obj
LINK : a.exe not found or not built by the last incremental link; performing full link
scons: done building targets.
```

Shouldn't `/Od` disable such optimizations? Assuming it's an optimization (but then, why not return nullptr early?)

Comment: The problem with stepping through with a debugger is that when something unexpected happens, it can be difficult to tell whether the program actually misbehaved, or whether the debugger is showing you misleading information (often due to a program optimization that confused the debugger's display).  If you want to differentiate between those two possibilities, I recommend temporarily inserting some `printf()` calls (or your favorite equivalent) into the function and running it again to see what gets printed.  Unlike a debugger, the printf-calls will reliably show you what really happened.

Comment: I've added `std::cout << "Calling free." << std::endl;` right before the breakpoint line and it does not print anything when returning `newMesh`, same with `printf`. Prints fine in the nullptr case. Also updated my VS proper (I use VS Code)  installation which I assume also updated the C++ workload, my project went through a full rebuild when I rebuilt in Code.

Comment: If I create the shared ptr first thing in the function, it also jumps straight to return and doesn't execute anything else in the function, what a weird thing, I've been working for months on this and never encountered something like this before. The code for the rest of the function is still there in the assembly though.

Comment: What happens if you put `cout` lines just before and just after the `std::make_shared` line?

Comment: I think it may be a quirk in the debugger after all... It jumps to `return` but if I keep stepping then it comes back and starts executing the rest of the code as normal.  This is so weird, it literally jumps to the line with the return statement but doesn't return. Sorry for the trouble, should've just stepped more. Still no clue why this behavior exists tho.

Comment: `Shouldn't /Od disable such optimizations?` - it could be [return value optimization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-nrvo?view=msvc-170): _Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4 increases the number of places where the compiler does optional copy or move elisions under /Zc:nrvo, whether enabled explicitly, or automatically by using the /O2, /permissive-, or /std:c++20 or later options._ - it seems they enable these optimization for `/std:c++20` even when built  with `/Od`, you can try to build with `/Zc:nrvo-`

Comment: @dewaffled that worked! thank you! please post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it, I had no idea "optimizations that are applied even when they're off" were a thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSVC has enabled [named returned value optimization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/zc-nrvo?view=msvc-170) (NRVO) when built with `/std:c++20` even in debug builds:

> Visual Studio 2022 version 17.4 increases the number of places where the compiler does optional copy or move elisions under /Zc:nrvo, whether enabled explicitly, or automatically by using the /O2, /permissive-, or /std:c++20 or later options.

It can be explicitly disabled with `/Zc:nrvo-` compiler option.

Note, nameless return value optimization (RVO) is [required](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) by the standard since C++17  and will always be performed regardless of `/Zc:nrvo`:

> When the nameless temporary is the operand of a return statement, this variant of copy elision is known as RVO, "return value optimization".
> (until C++17)

> Return value optimization is mandatory and no longer considered as copy elision; see above. (since C++17)